# java.lang.NullPointerException Exception error

Tags: java, swing, exception, nullpointerexception

i am running a JFrame on netbeans but am getting some errors that i have been unable to resolve. The complete Java code is given below

```
@EJB
private static displaysSessionBeanRemote displaysSessionBean;

@EJB
private static codesGenerateSessionBeanRemote codesGenerateSessionBean;
    String str1;
    String str2;
    String str3;
    String str4;
    String str5;       
String m = codesGenerateSessionBean.businessMethod(str1,str2,str3,str4,str5);
public NewJFrame() {

    this.str1 = serverName.getText();
    this.str2 = userName.getText();
    this.str3 = password.getText();
    this.str4 = databaseName.getText();
    this.str2 = tableName.getText();

    initComponents();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    serverName = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    userName = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    password = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    databaseName = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    tableName = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    jTextArea1 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jLabel1.setText("Server Name");

    serverName.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            serverNameActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jLabel2.setText("User Name");

    jLabel3.setText("Password");

    jLabel4.setText("Database name");

    jLabel5.setText("Table name");

    jButton1.setText("Generate PHP Codes");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jTextArea1.setColumns(20);
    jTextArea1.setRows(5);
    jTextArea1.addComponentListener(new java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter() {
        public void componentShown(java.awt.event.ComponentEvent evt) {
            jTextArea1ComponentShown(evt);
        }
    });
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTextArea1);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(33, 33, 33)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                .addComponent(jLabel3)
                .addComponent(jLabel4)
                .addComponent(jLabel5))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 136, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                .addComponent(tableName)
                .addComponent(databaseName)
                .addComponent(password)
                .addComponent(userName)
                .addComponent(serverName, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 124, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 319, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap())
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(93, 93, 93)
            .addComponent(jButton1)
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel1)
                        .addComponent(serverName, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel2)
                        .addComponent(userName, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel3)
                        .addComponent(password, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel4)
                        .addComponent(databaseName, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel5)
                        .addComponent(tableName, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                    .addComponent(jButton1))
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 178, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void serverNameActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                          

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                        

private void jTextArea1ComponentShown(java.awt.event.ComponentEvent evt) {                                          
    jTextArea1.setText(String.valueOf((m)));
}                                         
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JTextField databaseName;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea1;
private javax.swing.JTextField password;
private javax.swing.JTextField serverName;
private javax.swing.JTextField tableName;
private javax.swing.JTextField userName;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

After running it, this is the error that i get

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at NewJFrame.<init>(NewJFrame.java:20)
    at NewJFrame$4.run(NewJFrame.java:189)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

kindly assist as i am still new to java language

Comment: where is line 189 of your code ? past it here ?

Comment: I think in this line this.str2 = tableName.getText(); should be this.str5, check it

Comment: here goes my line 189 code:  new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);

Comment: where is NewJFrame class in your code ?

Comment: past your code with class name as well

Answer (score 1):

For starters, this:

```
this.str1 = serverName.getText();
this.str2 = userName.getText();
this.str3 = password.getText();
this.str4 = databaseName.getText();
this.str2 = tableName.getText();

initComponents();
```

Should instead be:

```
initComponents(); // make the components something other than null

this.str1 = serverName.getText();
this.str2 = userName.getText();
this.str3 = password.getText();
this.str4 = databaseName.getText();
this.str2 = tableName.getText();
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
     this.str2 = tableName.getText();
```

to

```
    this.str5 = tableName.getText();
```

Comment: Thanks @Aammad. I just made that change but it still has the same error.